# Pipeline parameter interferes with $args array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to make use of the `$args` array with a pipeline parameter.

The function expects an arbitrary number of parameters (e.g. param0) following the first, pipelined parameter:

```
function rpt-params {

    param ( 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0,Mandatory=$true)][CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument]$reportDocument
    )

    try {
        write-host "count: " $args.count

        #TODO process args

    }
    catch [Exception] {
        write-host $_.Exception
    }
    finally {
        return $reportDocument
    }

}
```

Attempts to call the function produce an error that reads "rpt-params : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'param0'.":

```
...
# syntax 0
rpt-params $rpt -param0 "mb-1" -param1 "me-1"
...

...
# syntax 1; explicitly naming the first parameter
rpt-params -reportDocument $rpt -param0 "mb-1" -param1 "me-1"
...
```

Is my syntax the issue or is it related to using a pipelined parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another parameter, called it something like $rest and decorate it with `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "[cmdletbinding()]" or "[Parameter()]", which is the case here, your Function turns into an Advanced Function. An Advanced Function can only take the Arguments that are specified under "Param" and no more. To make your Function act like before, like Keith recommends, you'll need to add `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]`

For Example:

```
function rpt-params {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument]$reportDocument,
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$args
    )

    try {
        write-host "count: " $args.count

        #TODO Now args can have all remaining values
    }
    catch [Exception] {
        write-host $_.Exception
    }
    finally {
        return $reportDocument
    }
}
```